# Combining Firoozbakht's conjecture and abc conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

[Firoozbakht's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture) states that for all $n\geq 1$ 
$$p_n^{\frac{1}{n}}>p_{n+1}^{\frac{1}{n+1}},$$
where $p_k$ the **kth prime number**. By asumption of this conjecture, for a fixed $n$, there is a positive integer $a_n$ such that 
$$p_n^{n+1}=a_n+p_{n+1}^n,$$
and combining with [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), since $gcd(a_n,p_{n+1}^n,p_n^{n+1})=1$, $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \mu(\epsilon)>0$ such that
$$p_n^{n-2}<\mu(\epsilon)rad(a_n)^{1+\epsilon}p_n^{3\epsilon},$$
where $rad(m)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n,\text{p, prime}}}p$, if $m>1$ and $rad(1)=1$. I've used Firoozbakht's conjecture for such deduction and poor computations. From $p_n^{n+1}=a_n+p_{n+1}^n$, one has unconditionally that 
$$p_n^{n+1}-p_{n}^n>a_n,$$
thus combining with the obvious fact that $rad(m)\leq m$, one has 
$$rad(a_n)<p_n^{n+1}-p_{n}^n.$$ But i know that this computation is poor too.

> **Question.** Can you improve my computations looking for a reasonable comparision between the Firoozbakht's conjecture and the abc conjecture? I say that you know improve my computations and know how combine with a more best strategy this statement for previous triples $(a_n,p_{n+1}^n,p_n^{n+1})$. What about $rad(a_n)$? I say if you can improve my bound using the equation for previous triples. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: In note **5** of Wikipedia's Page for Firoozbakht's conjecture ,I say in p. 2 of **Sinha's paper**, you can read a summary about comparision between conjectures and theorems on prime gaps. Feel free to add a comment if there are mistakes  in my post.

Comment: Today I wrote a variation of my calculations, if there are no mistakes in my calculations, presume that $(a_n,b_n,p^n_{n+1})$ is an abc triple (our positive integers are pairwise coprime and $a_n+b_n=p^n_{n+1}$ for a fixed $n$; notice that I don't know if such hypothesis is feasible) then the combination of cited conjectures (abc+Firoozbakht) yield the inequality $$p^n_{n+1}<C(\epsilon)\operatorname{rad}(a_nb_n)^{1+\epsilon}p_{n}^{(1+\epsilon)(1+1/n)}.$$  I don't know if these calculations, and those in the body of the post are interestings. If it isn't in the literature feel free to study it.